# Show that ${3 \over 2} \log{5} \leq \int_0^2{{x \over \sin{x}}d{x}} \leq \sqrt{6}\log{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})}$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

> Show that ${3 \over 2} \log{5} \leq \int_0^2{{x \over \sin{x}}d{x}} \leq \sqrt{6}\log{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})}.$

I can show that ${1 \over 2} \log{5} \leq \int_0^2{{x \over \sin{x}}d{x}}$ but not this. And for the right side, I have no idea. Can anyone give any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe on $[0, 2]$ we see that
\begin{align}
x-\frac{x^3}{3!} \leq \sin x \leq x-\frac{x^3}{9}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{9}{9-x^2}\leq \frac{x}{\sin x} \leq \frac{6}{6-x^2}.
\end{align}
Then we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{3}{2}\log 5=9\int^2_0 \frac{1}{9-x^2}\ dx\leq \int^2_0 \frac{x}{\sin x}\ dx \leq 6\int^2_0 \frac{dx}{6-x^2} = \sqrt{6}\log(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}).
\end{align}